# Simulating an RF remote control using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, rf, remote-control

I have a remote control for a video light, it's called 'Godox RC-A5'. The most detailed documentation I could find for it is here https://fccid.io/2ABYNRC-A5/Test-Report/Test-Report-2708894.pdf. The remote has 16 'channels' you can choose between and claims to operate in the 433.92MHz band.

I have an Arduino Uno with an RF receiver (https://components101.com/433-mhz-rf-receiver-module) and transmitter (https://components101.com/433-mhz-rf-transmitter-module). The documentation I linked to in the previous paragraph says that the remote control uses ASK modulation, so I tried using [this](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__ASK.html) but it didn't detect anything.

When I log raw input values from the receiver, I can tell it definitely goes high when I press a button on the remote control.

Is there any way in which I can look at the radio being sent from the remote control and decode it so that I can then replicate the signal and send it from my transmitter?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, and if it has a high enough bandwidth, try poking probes around on your receiver until you see the radio signal. If it has a lower bandwidth, it might still be useful to make an AM detector circuit tuned to 433MHz. ASK is basically just AM with a limited number of set points, after all.

Comment: Get  compatible receiver maybe an rtl sdr or you can typically rig up something to couple the power draw variation of an ASK/OOK transmitter into a computer soundcard.

Comment: Actually, is it not enough to just look at the output of the receiver module? Stick your scope on that, record the waveform while it's transmitting, and do whatever analysis you want on it.

Comment: Try using the old school method of  reading high frequency signals - a demodulator probe! Cobble one together with a diode cap and resistor of appropriate values for the frequency, to use with a scope or DVM. Are you keying the signal on and off? Is it possible it needs a continuous carrier keyed high and low? Comment back if you need details on the probe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually just finished an arduino library for this exact thing, although only the first 2 channels work so far. Try this, see if it works (assuming you still need it) https://github.com/BrittonPlewes/GodoxRemote

You for sure can see the signal on a scope, but I had to make my own version of [SimpleRcScanner](https://github.com/sui77/SimpleRcScanner) to capture and analyze the signal.

Comment: While that's perhaps useful, ultimately answers on stack exchange sites are required to be more than just links to external content.  To an extent, this indicates a problem with the question: it's not really answerable within the scope of stack exchange rules and should have long ago been closed.